# WebGrid Sorting is not working with Orchard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I have applied Webgrid in my orchard custom module and paging is working fine but I have facing issue in sorting.
sorting is only working on one column which is set as defaultSort another column sorting is not working.

```
<div id="gridList">
                @{
    var grid = new WebGrid<Models.ServicePart>(null, rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize, canPage: true, defaultSort: "Name", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "myGrid");
                    grid.Bind(Model.ServiceList, rowCount: Model.TotalCount, autoSortAndPage: false);
                    grid.Pager(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All);
                }
                <div id="myGrid">
                    @MvcHtmlString.Create(grid.GetHtml(tableStyle:"items", columns: grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column("Name",header: "Name",style:"width30percent"),
                    grid.Column(columnName:"Contact",header: "Contact", style:"width30percent"),
                    grid.Column("ServiceTypeRecord.TypeName",header: "Service Type",style:"width25percent"),
                    grid.Column("", header: "Action", format :(item) => Html.Raw(
                        (Authorizer.Authorize(Permissions.EditContent, item) ?  (Html.ItemEditLink(T("Edit").Text, item)).ToString() : "") + " | " + (Authorizer.Authorize(Permissions.EditContent, item) ?  (Html.Link(T("Delete").Text, Url.ItemRemoveUrl(item, new { returnUrl }), new { itemprop = "RemoveUrl UnsafeUrl" })).ToString() : "")
                      ),style:"width15percent")
                    )).ToString())
                </div>
            </div>
```

sorting only working on Name column because it is default sorting.If set column contact as default so only contact column sort working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

required column names when binding my model to the webgrid so Please add column name in grid.Bind Function sorting will work.

```
  var grid = new WebGrid<Models.ServicePart>(null, rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize, canPage: true, defaultSort: "Name", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "myGrid");
                grid.Bind(Model.ServiceList,new[]{"Name","Contact","ServiceTypeRecord.TypeName"}, rowCount: Model.TotalCount, autoSortAndPage: false);
                grid.Pager(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All);
```